# How can I test Mailchimp radio buttons in PHP?

Tags: php, radio-button, mailchimp

I have a Mailchimp radio button setup for Yes/No.  I'm having trouble testing it's value from PHP with something like this...

```
function draw_results_detail ($hitNum) {
    $result = '';
    if ($hitNum >= count($_SESSION['hitList'])) return $result;
    if ($hitNum < 0) return $result;

    $aHit = $_SESSION['hitList'][(int) $hitNum];

    $result .= sprintf(
    "%s %s<h2>%s %s</h2>",
    $aHit->membership,
    $aHit->affiliation,
    htmlspecialchars(capitalize_scrub($aHit->fname)),
    htmlspecialchars(capitalize_scrub($aHit->lname))
    );

    if (FALSE !== strpos(strtolower($aHit->unlisted),'yes')) {
        $result .= "<p>Email address and telephone number are unlisted.</p>";
    } else {
        $result .= sprintf(
        "<p>Email: <a href=\"mailto:%s\">%s<a/>" . 
        "<br/>Phone: %s</p>",
        htmlspecialchars(strtolower($aHit->email)),
        htmlspecialchars(strtolower($aHit->email)),
        htmlspecialchars(strtolower($aHit->phone))
        );
    }
        $temp = $aHit->modified;
    if ($temp != '') {
        $result .= "<span style=\"font-size:10px;\">(last modified: $temp UTC)</span>"; 
    }
    $temp = count($_SESSION['hitList']);
    $hitNum += 1;
    $result .= "<span style=\"font-size:10px;\"> [$hitNum of $temp]</span>";
    return $result;
}
```

The central IF statement fails to trigger.  If I "var_dump" $aHit, the "unlisted" key is String(0) even though Mailchimp shows the corresponding record's button is selected to Yes.

How can I test the button setting from Mailchimp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the text of the Mailchimp radio button items EXACTLY matches the text of the corresponding SQL data element.

In this case, a webhook was updating the SQL record whenever Mailchimp data was modified.  The text of the item wasn't being set correctly.

Rookie mistake, and not even in the snippet shown.  Sorry for the confusion.